# SharePoint web part that has "more"/"less" option

Tags: sharepoint

I'd like to find a web part that can display items from a SharePoint list, and also have the option to only show a summary of the content of a field along with a link to display the complete text.

It doesn't have to be free.

Comment: Looks like you are looking for consulting options heh?

Answer (score 2):

You can create your own web part; something similar to out of the box List viewer web part.

1. In your CreateChildControls() method define some grid columns;
2. Create data sources and get data from different lists for these columns.
3. Use SPMenuField, following methods will be useful:

SPMenuField.NavigateUrlFields 
SPMenuField.NavigateUrlFormat
SPMenuField.TokenNameAndValueFields

To quote from MSDN blogs:
SPMenuField "serves two purposes - it configures the hyperlink you follow if you click on the item directly and, optionally, links to a snazzy dropdown menu."

Follow the complete article here:
[SPGridView and SPMenuField: Displaying custom data through SharePoint lists.](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/powlo/archive/2007/02/25/displaying-custom-data-through-sharepoint-lists-using-spgridview-and-spmenufield.aspx)

Comment: Yes, that is actually the plan. However my employer feels more comfortable if we buy one already developed. Weird, I know.